# Complicated formula for a user form (2)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I am working on a user form where I need to find a way to add a certain amount of "additional hours" (`D:48 to D:51`) based on the "means of transport" (`L:19 to L:24`) selected by the user.

[image]

please note that `L:19` to `L:24` has a drop down list of type of transport as listed below. Each trip number (1 to 4) has to have its own time added (`D:48` to `D:51`). The amount of time to be added per "means of transport" type is as follows:

[image]

Many thanks in advance
Abe

Comment: @ScottCraner I created another post as suggested. thank you Scott

Comment: You question es vague, please can you explain in more detail what you did, and you want, and if you want a formula or VBA code.

Comment: whenever a "means of transport" is selected from a drop down list under L:19 to L:24, I want the related hours to be added to each trip number. For instance, trip number 1 on raw 19 & 20 has "train - standard premium, semi flexible" twice which is 2 x 0.5hour according to the table above so D48=1. I hope this makes sense

Comment: And how you relate the contries and cities??? In a hidden cells??? Which city is the reference? Column B or column F?

Comment: I assume you have the above list of means of transport somewhere in the workbook.  Could you give that reference?  We will need that reference to build any type of formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a helper column in P, this can be hidden.  In this column you would use a vlookup to your table of "Means of Transportation".  So if your lookup table is on sheet2 in A1:B11 then in P19 on your user form put

```
=VLOOKUP(L19,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$B$11,2,False)
```

And copy down.

Then in D48 use A simple SumIf() function:

```
=SUMIF($A$19:$A$24,A48,$P$19:$P$24)
```

And copy down

This should give you the results you are looking for.

Or If you want one formula to do it all then use the following Array Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$11,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$11,$L$19:$L$24)*($A$19:$A$24=A48))
```

Put in D48, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.